# Directive attributes are read as string rather than Date

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-directive

I am using a custom validator directive to validate the dateStart and dateEnd of my input fields as follow :

```
<input name="dateStart" type="text" [(ngModel)]="contract.startDate" 
       #dateStart="ngModel" style="width:100%" bsDatepicker required>

<input name="dateEnd" type="text" [(ngModel)]="contract.endDate"
       #dateEnd="ngModel" style="width:100%" bsDatepicker required
       myDateValidator dateStart="contract.startDate" dateEnd="contract.endDate">
```

This is my custom validator :

**date-validator.directive.spec.ts**

```
import { DateValidator } from './date-validator.directive';

describe('DateValidator', () => {
  it('should create an instance', () => {
    const directive = new DateValidator();
    expect(directive).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

**date-validator.directive.ts**

```
import { Directive, forwardRef, Attribute } from '@angular/core';
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
import { Validator, AbstractControl, NG_VALIDATORS } from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
  selector: '[myDateValidator][formControlName],[myDateValidator][formControl],[myDateValidator][ngModel]',
    providers: [
        { provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: forwardRef(() => DateValidator), multi: true }
    ]
})
export class DateValidator implements Validator {

  constructor(@Attribute('dateStart') public dateStart: Date, 
              @Attribute('dateEnd') public dateEnd: Date) { }

  validate(c: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } | null {
    if (!this.dateStart || !this.dateEnd) {
        return null;
    }
    if (this.dateEnd < this.dateStart) {
      return {myDateValidator: false};
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

The issue I am having here is that both `dateStart` and `dateEnd` parameters do not read the actual values of `contract.startDate` and `contract.endDate`; which both are of type `Date`; respectively but they rather read them as text `'contract.startDate'` and `'contract.endDate'` in this order.

I also tried the following syntax :

```
dateEnd="{{contract.endDate}}"
```

It threw me this error message which fully makes sense :

```
Can't bind to 'dateEnd' since it isn't a known property of 'input'. #dateEnd="ngModel" myDateValidator [ERROR ->]dateEnd="{{contract.endDate}}"
```

Any help is more than welcome.

Comment: Your bindings look incorrect. They should be: `[dateStart]="contract.startDate" [dateEnd]="contract.endDate"`

Comment: @Brandon Actually `dateStart` and `dateEnd` are meant to be attributes/parameters to `myDateValidator`. They are not bound to my component.

Comment: Right, but without the brackets it will be interpreted as a string

Comment: @Brandon got any idea how to pass the actual values of `contract.startDate` and `contract.endDate` to `myDateValidator` parameters`dateStart` and `dateEnd` in this order ?

Comment: @Attribute doesn't respond to change detection, so if contact is populated async, that may be why you're not seeing data